# I don't understand part of a proof involving sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

It must be pretty trivial but I don't understand one part for the reverse containment relation, I don't understand why A* contains A` and why we A* is sigma field on $\Omega^{*}$ notice here $\Omega^{*}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at the definition of $A^{*}$. It uses two different kinds of $A'$ that are distinct typographically, but it's difficult to notice this. The notation is unfortunate.

Recall that you have one specific fixed $A'$ in this proof, the one given in the theorem. It's a subset of $\Omega'$. Now let me write the definition of $A^{*}$ better:

$A^{*} = \{B' \subseteq \Omega' : X^{-1}(B') \in \sigma(X^{-1}(A')\}$

Now it should be clear to you why $A^{*}$ contains $A'$. To see why it's a $\sigma$-field, verify all the closure requirements by going over via $X^{-1}$ to inside the $\sigma$-field 
$\sigma(X^{-1}(A')$, where everything is suitably closed. The proof will be very similar to the one done in part $(i)$ of this proof.